# How to install JavaEE capabilities in Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I installed Eclipse Indigo. At that time, I did not install the JavaEE edition of Indigo. Now I want to have the capabilities of JavaEE in my Indigo. Which plugin I should use for this. So that I can add Tomcat server and can get HTML/JSP syntax highlighting.

Following is my eclipse version screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eclipse Web Tools (WTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/). Here's the update site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/.

Note however that Eclipse Java EE edition contains some other features and plugins apart from WTP, so I would strongly encourage you to install fresh version of Eclipse Java EE and just connect it with your existing workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the Eclipse. Please look at following link

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F

Comment: I think this refers to updating Eclipse from older version upwards and not adding new features to existing installation